# GS5 heart rate monitor coming on all the time

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Since the Lollipop upgrade I've noticed that every time my Samsung GS5 is awake when anything (finger, table, etc.) comes near the heart rate monitor it activates the red led. How do I disable this battery drainer?

Answer (score 0):

I realized my wife's GS5 did not have this issue until she installed Google Fit. I uninstalled Google Fit from my phone and restarted it, problem fixed.